# SQL Server Transactional Replication - Can propagation of schema changes and data changes be controlled?

Tags: sql-server, replication, transactional-replication

In transaction replication, if schema changes happen first and then the data changes, will it happen the same way in subscriber as well?

If no, is there a way to control the order?

Answer (score 1):

> If schema changes happen first and then the data changes, will it happen the same way in subscriber as well?

Yes - replication keeps track of what needs to be done via reading the transaction log and replaying those transactions in LSN order to subscribers. You shouldn't have to worry about out-of-order operations in general.